# Azure IoT Edge - Module deployment/update

Tags: azure-iot-edge

If I have an Edge Device with several modules, I can then update one module without affecting the others, even if all modules are deployed with the same deployment manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't update the module image URI, environment settings or createOptions  of a module, it will keep running. This means that if you only update these options of one of your modules, only that one will be restarted, the rest will remain active.